# PostgreSQL: PREPARED statement with ANY($1)

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, any

I want to create a PREPARED STATEMENT where inputs are some integers whose count is not known.
The way I'm trying to do is

```
PREPARE prep_select_data AS SELECT ARRAY[$1, id], $1, * FROM tbl_data WHERE id = ANY($1);
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
LINE 1: ...ELECT ARRAY[$1, id], $1, * FROM tbl_data WHERE id = ANY($1);
                                                             ^
```

I'm not able to figure out the issue.

Please advise.

Regards,
Mayank

Comment: What is `$1` in this context? An array or a single value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As error says you need to specify your `$1` as array (of integers):

```
-- DEALLOCATE prep_select_data;
PREPARE prep_select_data (int[]) AS 
SELECT
    $1 || ARRAY[id], $1, *
FROM
    tbl_data 
WHERE
    id = ANY($1);
```

I changed `ARRAY[$1, id]` to `$1 || ARRAY[id]`, so result looks like:

```
EXECUTE prep_select_data ('{1, 2}');
 ?column? | ?column? | id | value 
----------+----------+----+-------
 {1,2,1}  | {1,2}    |  1 | aaa
 {1,2,2}  | {1,2}    |  2 | bbb
```

It's because (from [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)):

> multidimensional arrays must have
>   matching extents for each dimension. A
>   mismatch causes an error report.